# Writing valid RegEx for use in file/folder exclusion

Tags: regex, string

I'm trying to write two expressions to use in the files/folder Exclusion List for Code42 CrashPlan backup. Their support won't help with RegEx expressions, they just point me to their [KB article](https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/6/Configuring/Exclude_or_filter_files_using_file_type_and_regular_expressions_regex).

In their "File Exclusions" section, I'd like to:

1. exclude this folder specifically: `S:\Google Drive\Temp`
2. any file or folder containing the string `Backup_Excluded` anywhere in its name.

This is what I've got so far - but I have no way of knowing if they're correct:

1. `(?i).*Google Drive\\Temp` ...but since I really want to exclude a specific folder, not a pattern - do I need to escape the slashes and colon in the path of `S:\Google Drive\Temp`
2. `(?i).*Backup_Excluded`

*Research disclaimer: I know there are RegEx resources out there, but am unsure which flavor/syntax to use, as I'd imagine there are many. I was hoping those with more RegEx familiarity could advise.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you posted says:

> The Code42 app treats all file separators as forward slashes /.

So it seems you'd want to use `/` instead of `\\` in your regular expressions.

Colon doesn't need escaping.

`\` needs escaping because it's the escaping character itself.

`/` normally needs escaping because it is the default separators for regular expression sections. However, the examples in your link don't escape it, so only the matching section is implied, so no escaping.

Then you could probably use:

1. `S:/Google Drive/Temp`
   or `[A-Z]:/Google Drive/Temp` (to allow any drive)
2. `.*Backup_Excluded.*`

I probably wouldn't use `(?i)`, as the capitals in those strings are usually there, but that's your call.

Check out e.g. https://regex101.com/ to test your regular expressions (also in different flavours).

Comment: Thank you! But should it be `S:\/Google Drive\/Temp` or `S:/Google Drive/Temp` ? I don't get it... Why?

Comment: A full regular expression may be written as `<command>/<matching pattern>/<substitution>/<modifiers>`. So the `/` has a special meaning and you need to escape it when it occurs inside the matching pattern. This application only asks for the matching pattern, so it doesn't need you to escape it